# Applescript to fill in Keychain dialog box

Tags: applescript, keychain

I'd like to fill in the Keychain Dialog box with the Name: and Password fields (printer is windows print queue), but after the Print command, the Keychain dialog box opens up, but never responds to anything till I click OK or cancel.

```
  tell application "TextEdit"
  activate
  make new document

  print document 1 with properties {target printer:"2nd-floor"}

  tell application "System Events"

         set value of text field 1 of group 1 of window 1 to "CUA\name"

         click button 2 of window 1 of application process "SecurityAgent"

  end tell
  end tell
```

Hope I missing something silly, thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Consider altering the requirement for a password. Printers on Mac OS X are managed by the Common UNIX Printing System (CUPS) and it is highly configurable.

Mac OS X Hints published this, [Disable printer queue password requirements](http://hints.macworld.com/article.php?story=20081107092520601), for disabling printer queue passwords. It should work for modern versions of OS X:

> 1. As root, or in a Terminal session with `su` privileges, edit `/etc/cups/cupsd.conf`.
> 2. Find the section below.
> 3. Remove the items you don't want limited: `Pause-Printer`, `Resume-Printer`, `Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job`, etc.
> 4. Save the file, quit the editor, and restart your computer

Section to find and edit:

```
  <Limit Pause-Printer Resume-Printer Enable-Printer Disable-Printer Pause-Printer-After-Current-Job Hold-New-Jobs Release-Held-New-Jobs Deactivate-Printer Activate-Printer Res
tart-Printer Shutdown-Printer Startup-Printer Promote-Job Schedule-Job-After CUPS-Accept-Jobs CUPS-Reject-Jobs>
      AuthType Default
      Require user @AUTHKEY(system.print.admin) @admin @lpadmin
      Order deny,allow
  </Limit>
```

Comment: I think this all refers to the Administrative password for the Mac you are trying to print from.

I am looking to enter the domain\username and password for the windows print queue  (smb:\\server.com\printqueue) that our students are trying to print to.

Comment: Have you considered embedding your credentials in the `smb://` URL or used `smbpasswd` to store the password securely? http://willem.engen.nl/projects/cupssmb/ and http://www.samba.org/samba/docs/man/Samba-HOWTO-Collection/CUPS-printing.html might be useful for this approach.

Comment: Since my university forces students to change passwords every 6 months, I originally thought that would not work.  But the installing printers part of my applescript works well,  so that I am going to look at that method.   It would mean they would have to run the script again in 6 months when their password expires, but they were going to have to update their keychain anyway, thanks for the suggestion -Len